# AWS glue NoClassDefFoundError on job.init()

Tags: etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue3.0

Trying to debug AWS Glue scripts locally using Glue ETL library.
I have installed aws-glue-libs and spark-3.1.1-amzn-0-bin-3.2.1-amzn-3.tgz.

When I run `job.init()`, I get the following error trace:

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigMergeable
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job$.init(Job.scala:93)
at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job.init(Job.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigMergeable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 13 more

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error stacktrace as text and not just as an image, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: There's only 1 more post on Stack Overflow having  the [NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67506885) error on the aws-glue tag. Did you see the answer?

Comment: @bad_coder yes i tried that answer. The problem persists.

Comment: Not my downvote!! I don't now how to solve this problem (I don't work with AWS Glue) but check the link in the first comment, questions that don't have the full stacktrace included as text are closed per site-policy. Even if someone else knows the answer they're unlikely to attempt answering a question that doesn't include the stacktrace as text.

Answer (score 1):

This error wasn't resolved per say. But i found a workaround. Instead of running my scripts from pycharm, i run them using gluesparksubmit bash command. Now it doesn't throw error at job.init(). Still trying to figure out how to get access to data catalog when running glue scripts from local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If it was for `ConfigMergeable`, check if proper `jar` file - `config-1.3.3.jar` - exists in your `/opt/spark/jars` dir.

Whole idea is that jars in `/opt/spark/jars` and `./aws-glue-libs/jarsv1` should match.